# pywinauto: MenuSelect() Cannot be used to select options from "Menu ToolBar" in QGIS applications

Tags: python, qgis, pywinauto

I am trying to automate menu options selections from QGIS app but `MenuSelect("Project -> open")` is not working for the desktop app(QGIS) using. Getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: There is no menu.

```
    app = Application()
    app.connect(path=r"C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.28.5/bin/qgis-ltr-bin.exe")
    app.CriticaloverviewSampleFilesQGIS.draw_outline()
    app.CriticaloverviewSampleFilesQGIS.menu_select("Edit -> Select")
```

[image: menu toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try run your app with uia ?   `Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=".*yourapp.*")`